# Adding two levels of one-to-many to an admin form

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an admin page for creating invoices, which has an inline for package groups. I want to associate the fee information with package groups (consequently the `Fee` model has a `ForeignKey` to `PackageGroup`).

I want to be able to somehow modify and view the fees from the `Invoice` Add/Modify page, however. Popping out a window would be fine, as long as it's somehow there and editable.

Comment: It would help everyone if you were to post the relevant models in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, nested-inlines are not yet supported out-of-the-box in the django admin.  There is a 5+ year old open ticket on the issue: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025

I haven't used it, but there is a 3rd party app, django-nested-inlines, that supposedly does the trick.  You can find it here: https://github.com/Soaa-/django-nested-inlines

Or, you can do what I did.  Roll up your sleeves and hammer out your own Edit/create views.  Afterall, the admin interface wasn't intended for the end user.